# Adding Hyperlink to Table in PineScript

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I am creating a new indicator in PineScript with a Table.

I have the following piece of code (partial code posted for better understand):

```
s01 = input.symbol('AMARAJABAT',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's01')
s02 = input.symbol('APOLLOTYRE',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's02')


// Get only symbol
only_symbol(s) => 
    array.get(str.split(s, ":"), 1)

s_arr   = array.new_string(0)

array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s01))

table.cell(tbl, 0, i + 1, array.get(s_arr, i), text_halign = text.align_left,   bgcolor = color.gray, text_color = color.white, text_size = size.small)
```

..this successfully fetches the ticker symbol from the array.

How do I make this clickable so that I can click on the Table cell and the chart opens in Tradingview. I somehow want to do this:

```
https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=NSE: + array.get(s_arr, i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently a feature